# Including an href in mat-list-item not working

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to put an href into mat-list-item, so that it will work just the same as putting a routerLink in there.

```
                <mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.close()" class="expansion-indent-3">
                  <a href="http://apps.ma****oice.com/MOCHUB/SLG/Permissions">
                    Permissions
                  </a>
                </mat-list-item>
```

I tried putting an a tag within the mat-list-item, but that will only allow the user to click on the actual text and not the mat-list-item surrounding the text.

I also tried to use an a tag with the mat-list-item property within it like below, which I found from another article but has no functionality and does not work.

```
            <a mat-list-item href="http://apps.ma****oice.com/MOCHUB/SLG" *ngIf="slgNav || userCategory === 'Accounting' || userCategory === 'Buyer' || userCategory === 'Admin' || userCategory ==='StoreManager' || userCategory === 'DepartmentManager'" (click)="sidenav.close()" routerLink="/account" class="expansion-indent-2">

              <h6 matLine>SLG Store</h6>

            </a>
```

I'm surprised I can't find anyone having this issue.  I also think I should be able to add an href pretty easily to a mat-list-item and didn't think it would be this difficult.

Can anyone shed light on how to put an href in the mat-list-item so that it will work just the same as if I put the routerlink in there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For covering all mat-list content you can try this:

```
<a href="http://apps.ma****oice.com/MOCHUB/SLG/Permissions">
   <mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.close()" class="expansion-indent-3">
      <span>Permissions</span>
   </mat-list-item>                   
</a>
```

Comment: That seems to have worked!  Thanks!  I'm surprised I couldn't find any documentation regarding that.  I suppose not too many people are liking externally through their own side nav.  We do that because were linking our other app on a different domain.  Thanks!